# selection does not contain a main type error

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

so basically I have been given a task to add 5 methods to a class. I have been provided with 4 classes, of which we are only to edit 1. I have tried to run the program but I keep getting an error saying selection does not contain a main type. I am trying to execute the totalPack() method.

This is the class which contains my methods.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PackCards {

    private ArrayList<Card> pack;

    /*
     * Create a random pack of size n
     */
    public PackCards(int n) {
        Card c;
        pack = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            c = new Card();
            pack.add(c);
        }
    }

    public void printPack() {
        for (Card c : pack) {
            System.out.println(c.cardString());
        }
    }

    /*
     * Total the numerical value of all the cards in the pack
     */
    public int totalPack() {
            int total = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < PackCards.length; i++) {
                total = total + PackCards[i];
            }


        }
```

Below is the class which contains the main method, which is required to run the code.

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Edit number to control size of pack
        PlayCards player = new PlayCards(10);

        player.testTotal(); // Remove comments to test each method

        // Edit string for a different suit
        // player.testSuit("Hearts");

        // player.testLargest();

        // player.testDuplicate();

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share more information

Comment: basically this project models a pack of playing cards and I have to add methods which do different things to the cards, for example return the value of all the cards added up. the class which I have to edit is the packCards.java class. this class contains all my methods. the driver.java class is the class which contains the main method. when I execute the packCards.java class, I get the "selection does not contain a main type" error.

Comment: You can't run a class without main method. that's why you are getting this message. if you want to make PackCards.java executable you should have main method in it or run the methods of pack cards from Driver class. also you can use static or systme.exit() if you want to run without main method

Comment: so should I copy the main method from driver.java to packCards.java?

Comment: You should be only executing Driver.class. I can only assume that player.testTotal() invokes PackCards totalPack() and prints the result. You did not show this class so I cannot say for sure. You cannot directly run PackCards from the commandline however as it does not contain a main method.

Comment: I have tried running driver.java, which is the class with the main method, but I still get the error

Comment: I just realised that I wasn't running the correct class. thank you very much for all your help. It is much appreciated